# My NN Custom Loss Function shows "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I am writing a simple neural network code to learn a gambling game. At some point after evaluating the results, I might use a deeper neural network.

## Parameters

The parameters are:

- gamma = 0.99
- N = 32
- N_prime = 8
- K = 32

  ```
    tau = np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)
    tau_prime = np.random.uniform(0, 1, N_prime)
    tau_tilde = np.random.uniform(0, 1, K)
    tau_tilde_beta = np.zeros(K)
    for k in range(K):
       tau_tilde_beta[k] = beta(tau_tilde[k])
    batch_size = 32
  ```

(beta is just a function from the real numbers to the real numbers, we can take it to be something like beta(x)=x^2)

## Loss Function

This is a custom loss function I built.

```
    def IQN_Loss(new_true_value, new_pred_value):

      Z_x_tau = np.zeros((2, N))
      for a in range(2):
        for j in range(N):
          X = np.array([[prev_state[0], prev_state[1], a, tau[j]]])
          Z_x_tau[a, j] = model.predict(X, batch_size=None)

      Z_beta_x_tau_tilde = np.zeros((2,K))
      for a in range(2):
        for k in range(K):
          X_tilde = np.array([[prev_state[0], prev_state[1], a, tau_tilde_beta[k]]])
          Z_beta_x_tau_tilde[a, k] = model.predict(X_tilde, batch_size=None)

      Z_x_prime_tau_prime = np.zeros((2,N_prime))
      for a in range(2):
        for k in range(N_prime):
          X_prime = np.array([[state[0], state[1], a, tau_prime[k]]])
          Z_x_prime_tau_prime[a, k] = model.predict(X_prime, batch_size=None)

      a_star = np.argmax((1 / K) * np.sum(Z_x_tau, axis=1))
      a_star_prime = np.argmax((1 / K) * np.sum(Z_x_prime_tau_prime, axis=1))

      delta = np.zeros((batch_size, N, N_prime))
      for e in range(batch_size):
        for i in range(N):
          for j in range(N_prime):
            delta[e, i, j] = new_true_value[e, 0] + gamma * Z_x_prime_tau_prime[a_star_prime, j] - Z_x_tau[a_star, i]

      L_kappa = np.zeros((batch_size, N, N_prime))
      for e in range(batch_size):
        for i in range(N):
          for j in range(N_prime):
            if abs(delta[e, i, j]) < kappa:
              L_kappa[e, i, j] = 0.5 * (delta[e, i, j]) ** 2
            else:
              L_kappa[e, i, j] = kappa * (abs(delta[e, i, j] - 0.5 * kappa))

      rho_tau_kappa = np.zeros((batch_size, N, N_prime))
      for e in range(batch_size):
        for i in range(N):
          for j in range(N_prime):
            if delta[e, i, j] < 0:
              rho_tau_kappa[e, i, j] = abs(tau[i] - 1) * L_kappa[e, i, j] / kappa
            else:
              rho_tau_kappa[e, i, j] = abs(tau[i]) * L_kappa[e, i, j] / kappa

      rho_expected = (1 / N_prime) * np.sum(np.sum(rho_tau_kappa, axis=2), axis=1)
      return rho_expected
```

## Neural Network Definition

```
    model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential([
tensorflow.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(4, )), 
tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')])

    model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',
         loss='huber_loss',
         metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am thinking the calculations for delta are correct, because:

- new_true_value is a 32 by 1 numpy array
- Z_x_prime_tau_prime is a 2 by N_prime=8 numpy array
- Z_x_tau is a 2 by N=32 numpy array
  so the dimensions are correct, and delta becomes a 32 by 2 by 32 numpy array.

However, the error message is as shown:

Error Message:
[image: error]

Could I check what is causing the array replacement error for delta?

Comment: You cannot use this as a loss, its implemented using numpy, you have to implement it with the keras backend or directly in tensorflow code.

Comment: Thank you! Is it ok to share any page of how to set a custom loss function in Keras backend?